# Media Query is not applied

Tags: html, css

Media queries not applying, I'm trying to setup a MQ for iphone

This is the HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="logo">
            </div>

                <div class="nav">

                </div>

                    <div id="leftfooter">
                        <div id="colorfoot">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>


    <div class="right">
                <div class="rightt">
                    <div class="main">
                        <h1 class="headers">Curriculum</h1>

                                        <div id="primelists">
                                            <div id="primelist1">

                                            </div>

                                            <div id="primelist2">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="right_footer">
                            <div class="labels">

                            </div>
            </div>
    </div

</body>

</html>

<body>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="logo">
            </div>

                <div class="nav">

                </div>

                    <div id="leftfooter">
                        <div id="colorfoot">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>


    <div class="right">
                <div class="rightt">
                    <div class="main">
                        <h1 class="headers">Curriculum</h1>

                                        <div id="primelists">
                                            <div id="primelist1">

                                            </div>

                                            <div id="primelist2">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="right_footer">
                            <div class="labels">

                            </div>
            </div>
    </div

</body>

</html>`
```

This is my current main CSS

```
.right {
    padding: 0 0 0 270px;
    border-right: 10px solid #C9CACE;
}

.left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 248px;
    background: url('../img/bg.gif') repeat;
}
```

This is my media query

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)  {
    .right {
        padding: 0 0 0 270px;
        border-right: 10px solid #C9CACE;
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .left {
        position: static;
        display: table-cell;
        width: 248px;
        background: url('../img/bg.gif') repeat;
    }
}
```

It seems my media query still applies the position, top, left and height from my main styling, how do I fix this?

Comment: It seems that your media query applies the settings in your media query? What?

Comment: I think you should use min-width max-width rather than min-device-width....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not changing the position property in media query area.. Change it to

```
.left {
      position:static;
 }
```

**EDIT**

use only  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px)  { }

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyqjr/

Comment: Strangely the mobile browser is still displaying the left column as fixed even though I've specified it as position: static in the MQ

Comment: what I assume, you need to set padding-left:0 for media query along with position:static; can you show the actual html markup?

Comment: It's up now, sorry : )

Comment: Wow, I really thought that was going to work... I've pasted your exact code, and I can see it works on fiddle, but on my iPhone it's display the left column as red, as if the query isn't effecting it. I'm wondering now, maybe it's my phone that is the problem?

Comment: Oh, my apologies Nitesh! Your code is flawless, it's my stupidity, I forgot the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;"> Thanks for your help, you're a legend!

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
top: inherit;
left:inherit;
height: auto;
```

Comment: Nope, no effect to the mobile layout

Answer (score 0):

use this condition

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) 
{

}
```

Comment: I've added it, my problem still remains.

Comment: yes this condition work when your browser width lying between 320 to 480

Comment: I tested it on my iphone.